# Configure nginx routing for a cloudfoundry application

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry

I have a static cloudfoundry application deployed on www.mycompany.com

When users go to www.mycompany.com/rate, I want the page to be forwarded to myrate.apps.mycompany.com/summary

The static app contains a nginx.conf.
Below is my configuration which works.

```
server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /rate {
        proxy_pass http://myrate.apps.mycompany.com/summary;
    }

    location = /rate/ {
        proxy_pass http://myrate.apps.mycompany.com/summary;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. http://myrate.apps.mycompany.com/summary is using some css and js files at:

- http://myrate.apps.mycompany.com/js/myjs.js
- http://myrate.apps.mycompany.com/css/mycss.css

How do I also proxy those resources?

Without any proxy it will result in 404 www.mycompany.com/rate/js/myjs.js

Cheers,
Ken

Comment: Sure, this can be configured in Nginx. It would help if you posted your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You can push your application using the "staticfile" buildpack and specify a custom Nginx configuration! See http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#custom_nginx_configuration and https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack

Comment: It should be noted this answer is outdated. PCF now offers an NGINX buildpack (see: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/index.html) which also supports a custom NGINX config.